# merge multiple date and time columns into a datetime column R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

For data below:

```
> dt
         date   event1   event2   event3
1: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09
2: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09
3: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09
4: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09
5: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09
```

I'd like to merge `date` with each of the event columns to make the event time columns into a `datetime` format. Desired output:

```
dt$event1 = as.POSIXct(paste(dt$date, dt$event1), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt$event2 = as.POSIXct(paste(dt$date, dt$event2), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt$event3 = as.POSIXct(paste(dt$date, dt$event3), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt$date = NULL

  > dt
                event1              event2              event3
1: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
2: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
3: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
4: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
5: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
```

Since I have quite a large dataset with >300k rows and >20 event time columns, what's the **most efficient way to do this at once for all event time columns** in either `dplyr` or `data.table` please?

Sample data:

```
dt = data.table(date = rep(as.POSIXct("2016-04-27"),5), event1 = rep("10:25:15",5), event2 = rep("11:05:45",5), event3 = rep("13:00:09",5))
```

Comment: Can you please provide a desired output?

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the duplication. In the example, `event1` could just be replaced instead of generating `event1_datetime` - will update question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` to add new columns

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("event")), funs(as.POSIXct(paste0(date, .)))) %>%
  select(-date)

#               event1              event2              event3
#1 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
#2 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
#3 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
#4 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
#5 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
```

Comment: Thank you!  and thanks for updating your answer after my question was edited - really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what this has to do with a merge; isn't this just

```
dt[, event1_datetime := as.POSIXct(paste(date, event1))]
#         date   event1   event2   event3     event1_datetime
#1: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
#2: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
#3: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
#4: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
#5: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
```

---

### Update

For what it's worth, here's a `data.table` solution using `melt` and `dcast`

```
dt[, n := 1:.N]
dt <- melt(dt[, n := 1:.N], id.vars = c("date", "n"), value.name = "time")
dt[, datetime := as.POSIXct(paste(date, time))]
dt <- dcast(dt, date + n ~ variable, value.var = c("time", "datetime"))
dt[, n := NULL]
#         date time_event1 time_event2 time_event3     datetime_event1
#1: 2016-04-27    10:25:15    11:05:45    13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
#2: 2016-04-27    10:25:15    11:05:45    13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
#3: 2016-04-27    10:25:15    11:05:45    13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
#4: 2016-04-27    10:25:15    11:05:45    13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
#5: 2016-04-27    10:25:15    11:05:45    13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15
#       datetime_event2     datetime_event3
#1: 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
#2: 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
#3: 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
#4: 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
#5: 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
```

Or all in one go

```
dcast(melt(dt[, n := 1:.N], id.vars = c("date", "n"), value.name = "time")[,
    datetime := as.POSIXct(paste(date, time))], 
    date + n ~ variable, value.var = c("time", "datetime"))[,
    n := NULL][]
```

Comment: yes, but I'd like to do that for all event columns (`event1`, `event2`, `event3` etc, all at once.

Comment: Ah I see; ok, in that case reshaping from wide to long, then adding the date, and reshaping back to wide will work. I will post an update...

Comment: @pyne For what it's (still) worth, I've added a `data.table` solution that accounts for an arbitrary number of event columns.

Comment: Thank you, @Maurits Evers - I generally find `data.table` to be faster, so great to have the option!

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach using `.SDcols`:

```
cols <- paste0(grep("^event", names(dt), value=TRUE), "_datetime")
dt[, (cols) := 
    lapply(.SD, function(x) as.POSIXct(paste(date, x), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 
        .SDcols=event1:event3]
```

output:

```
         date   event1   event2   event3     event1_datetime     event2_datetime     event3_datetime
1: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
2: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
3: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
4: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
5: 2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09 2016-04-27 10:25:15 2016-04-27 11:05:45 2016-04-27 13:00:09
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("date   event1   event2   event3
2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09
2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09
2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09
2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09
2016-04-27 10:25:15 11:05:45 13:00:09")
```